# Reverse a PWM pulse with hardware

Tags: transistors, mosfet, switches, pwm, bjt

I want to create a PWM pulse that is 180 degrees phase difference with another PWM pulse.
In other words, when the original PWM is HIGH, the second pulse will be 0 Volts.
When the original PWM is 0V, the second pulse will be HIGH.

What is an efficient way to do this? I am thinking perhaps there is a transistor way to do this.. Either with BJTs or MOSFETs. They could be used as a switch, so that the first PWM controls the output.

Ideally, i would want an approach with a component that is easily accessible. My concern is, is it possible that the two signals will remain in sync? So that there is a true 180 degrees difference between them?

EDIT: This is the final pulse that i want to generate, via an H-Bridge:
[image]

Comment: Without putting tolerances on their, the answer to "can you get a true 180° out of phase' is no, truly 180° is impossible. Please edit your question and add detail of why you are trying to make this and within what limits.

Comment: What about a simple inverter gate? There will be a small delay through the component but it might be small enough if your switching frequency isn’t that high.

Comment: @jakob yes and the delay could be compensated by feeding the non-inverted signal through a buffer with equal delay to the inverter.

Comment: From your description, I think you want to invert the signal, not have a 180 degree phase difference.  I don't know how I would define a phase difference for a PWM signal.

Comment: Yeah, even if we could unambiguously define phase of a PWM signal, what op describes is clearly just an inversion.

Comment: @TonyM They will be inputs to an H-Bridge. I seriously don't know of any limits.. I know there can be tolerances, but i am not sure to what extent.

Comment: @mkeith Thanks! It is easy to please write answer for this? This is the first time i am hearing of this concept. When buffer, you mean an opamp topology?

Comment: Since it is going to an H bridge, the best thing might be to use a half bridge driver (or two half-bridge drivers).

Comment: @mkeith Ultimately, the H-Bridge will create a relatively high voltage AC square pulse. Imagine a square pulse that goes in both positive and negative voltages. Can i achieve this functionality with a half bridge driver? I updated the question with a picture of the final pulse that i want to create.

Comment: You need an H-bridge as you say. That means you need to generate control signals for 4 mosfets. You have mentioned generating two signals. I am not sure whether, in your mind, the two signals are top and bottom of same side of bridge, or if one controls one side and the other controls the other side. The issue is that if they are top and bottom of same side, then you also need to account for "dead time" to avoid shoot-through. If one signal is for the left, and one signal is for the right, then no dead time is needed and the switching delay is not so critical.

Answer (score 2):

An inverter can do this, be it constructed from a gate or discrete transistor.

The nature of your question however leads me (and others apparently) to speculate why you need to invert your signal. And based on the comments, it seems you intend to drive an H bridge or somesuch. Otherwise, you could just reprogram your microcontroller to flip the phase.

Look up a ‘non-overlapping clock generator’. This can be constructed with CMOS gates. Why non-overlapping? To ensure no shoot-through when controlling switches.

Or consider a driver IC, or  bridge that has this anti-shoot-through built in.

Comment: Thank you! But the PWM will be generated from a microcontroller. This is fixed, and I don't have any control over this.

Comment: Yes, and the usual reason one wishes to have two phases of a PWM signal is to drive a pair of FETs on the same side of a bridge. Therefore it’s important that there be ‘dead time’ between the phases, which the non-overlapping generator will accomplish. There are also gate driver ICs that will do this.

Comment: This is interesting, can you expand a bit? From what i understood, you suggest two different approaches. The one is that the signal will pass through two different MOSFETS, in order to get both the buffered PWM and the inverted PWM? The second with the gate driver IC, i didn't get... Could you please say a thing or two about it?

Comment: Your question is kind of an XY problem. You're asking to do a very narrow specific thing which you *think* is what you need, but in reality there needs to be more detail and analysis before the kaffeklatsch here can recommend a solution. Provide a schematic and let's see what we can do.

Comment: I don't have a schematic just yet. I updated the question with a picture, of the final pulse that i want to create.

Comment: As to why i want to do this. I want to drive two LED strips.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how much delay you can tolerate between the two signals, you just need an inverter. You can create one with a mosfet or a BJT like you're already thinking, just connect your signal to the gate in the case of a mosfet, and a pull up resistor from your positive rail to the drain. When the input signal goes high, it will cause the mosfet to saturate and connect a resistance to ground. There are also a whole slew of inverters in the 4000 series and 7400 series logic families that may be OK for you, just be sure to check input voltage ranges, and supply voltage ranges for compatibility with your project.

Comment: Thank you! You mean a circuit like this? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nCbdMWc6MCU . Please look only at the circuit at 6:10.

Comment: That will certainly do it if you are implementing all of this on a chip... my suggestion is more of a board level answer. I was suggesting just a single n-channel mosfet with a pull-up resistor from the drain to Vdd. In that configuration, a positive voltage above the Vgs threshold voltage will cause the mosfet to pull that resistor to ground. If you probe the drain, you will see a signal that is the inversion of the PWM signal driving the gate. Its small, simple, and will work so long as you can tolerate the delay/slew.

Comment: To add some color to the answer though, this is entirely dependent on your application. A DC/DC converter using a synchronous rectifier for example may suffer some serious losses due to delay in these signals depending on operating frequency, load, etc. Some more detail as to what you are actually doing will help a lot in getting more pointed answers from the community! Like with all engineering problems, there are MANY solutions, but each comes with drawbacks that need to be weighed against your requirements

Comment: I am building an LED strip driver. I like the idea of the single MOSFET solution. Unfortunately, i did not find any configuration like the one you described. The PWM pulse will be around 500Hz. Is it too much if i asked you to create a small diagram of the MOSFET configuration please?